# Выделить тетрадные клетки на изображении python cv2

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Задача следующая - требуется на тетрадном листе, исписанным текстом, линиями выделить клетки.

Пытался сделать это через **CV2**, а именно - через выделение границ `canny edges`.

Проблема в том, что текст имеет более выраженную структуру, чем клетки, и `canny edges` выделяет текст, но не клетку. При увеличении параметра появляется огромная зашумленность, с чем нельзя работать.

Для примера можно взглянуть на это картинку. Здесь требуется расчертить клетку при помощи линии.

[image]

Вот результат canny edges при минимальном параметре
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При увеличении этого параметра зашумленность резко возрастает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли еще варианты, которые позволяют выделить линии клеток, минуя текст?

Comment: Мб попробовать поискать по цвету? Вот пример поиска по цвету (hsv): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/1f5aa0347b744156b7a5b0b750eed8ff0b03b36d/opencv__examples/find_objects_by_color__hsv

Comment: @gil9red, мысль интересная, но проблема в том, что это лишь один пример. Могут попадаться и чёрно-белые сканы. Так что строго указывать цвет не получится.Тем более, цвет ручки и клеток несколько похож.

Comment: Гуглил и нашел кое-что интересное: cv2.HoughLines

Comment: @gil9red, HoughLines используется, когда правильно получены edges. У меня, увы, результат несколько печальный (фотки выше)